# Simple java calculation code not working fully

Tags: java, math, calculator

I have been creating a calculator as a beginner in Java. I have added in buttons that have a more complex functionality, and for some reason they just don't work.

Can somebody please educate me on why these java calculations are not working properly?
The buttons that work fine are the plus, minus, multiply and divide. 
The buttons that aren't working so well are the **percentage**, **squareRt**, and the **PlusMinus** buttons.

You can see in the calculator engine that I have implemented the correct method of calculation, however when the problematic buttons are pressed, the text display area of the calculator goes blank, when for example, if you press in 64 on the calculator and then press sqrt, it is suppose to display the Square root of 64, but is not doing so. Thanks for any help in advance. (take it easy on me i'm a beginner)

**Here is the calculator**

```
package Calculator;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Calculator {

// Declare and instantiate window components
JButton button0 = new JButton("0");
JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
JButton buttonPoint = new JButton(".");
JButton buttonEqual = new JButton("=");
JButton buttonPlus = new JButton("+");
JButton buttonMinus = new JButton("-");
JButton buttonDivide = new JButton("/");
JButton buttonMultiply = new JButton("*");
JButton buttonSquareRt = new JButton("sqrt");
JButton buttonPercentage = new JButton("%");
JButton buttonPlusMinus = new JButton("+/-");
JButton buttonClear = new JButton("C");


JPanel windowContent = new JPanel();
JTextField displayField = new JTextField(30);

// Constructor
Calculator() {

    // Set the layout manager for this panel

    BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
    windowContent.setLayout(bl);

    // Add the display field to the top of the window

    windowContent.add("North", displayField);

    // Create the panel with the GridLayout
    // that will contain 12 buttons - 10 numeric ones, and
    // buttons with the point and the equal sign

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(4, 3);
    p1.setLayout(gl);

    p1.add(button1);
    p1.add(button2);
    p1.add(button3);
    p1.add(button4);
    p1.add(button5);
    p1.add(button6);
    p1.add(button7);
    p1.add(button8);
    p1.add(button9);
    p1.add(button0);
    p1.add(buttonPoint);
    p1.add(buttonEqual);

    // Add the panel p1 to the centre area of the window
    windowContent.add("Center", p1);

    // Create the panel with the GridLayout
    // that will contain 4 action buttons -
    // Plus, Minus, Divide and Multiply

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    GridLayout gl2 = new GridLayout(4, 1);
    p2.setLayout(gl);
    p2.add(buttonPlus);
    p2.add(buttonMinus);
    p2.add(buttonMultiply);
    p2.add(buttonDivide);

    //adding the task buttons to go on extra column
    p2.add(buttonSquareRt);
    p2.add(buttonPercentage);
    p2.add(buttonPlusMinus);
    p2.add(buttonClear);

    // Add the panel p2 to the east area of the window
    windowContent.add("East", p2);


    // Create the frame and add the content pane to it
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");

    frame.setContentPane(windowContent);

    // set the size of the window to be big enough to
    // accommodate all window controls

    frame.pack();

    // Display the window
    frame.setVisible(true);
    // Instantiate the event listener and

    // register each button with it

    CalculatorEngine calcEngine = new CalculatorEngine(this);

    button0.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    button1.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    button2.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    button3.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    button4.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    button5.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    button6.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    button7.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    button8.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    button9.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonPoint.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonPlus.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonMinus.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonDivide.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonMultiply.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonEqual.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonSquareRt.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonPercentage.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonPlusMinus.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    buttonClear.addActionListener(calcEngine);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Instantiate the class Calculator
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
}
}
```

**And here is the engine with the problematic code**
    package Calculator;

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class CalculatorEngine implements ActionListener {

Calculator parent; // a reference to Calculator window
char selectedAction = ' '; // +, -, /, or *

double currentResult = 0;

// Constructor stores the reference to the Calculator
// window in the member variable parent
CalculatorEngine(Calculator parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // Get the source of this action
    JButton clickedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
    String dispFieldText = parent.displayField.getText();
    double displayValue = 0;
    // Get the number from the text field
    // if it’s not empty
    if (!"".equals(dispFieldText)) {
        displayValue = Double.parseDouble(dispFieldText);
    }
    Object src = e.getSource();
    // For each action button memorize selected
    // action +, -, /, or *, store the current value
    // in the currentResult, and clean up the display
    // field for entering the next number

    if (src == parent.buttonPlus) {
        selectedAction = '+';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.displayField.setText("");
    } else if (src == parent.buttonMinus) {
        selectedAction = '-';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.displayField.setText("");
    } else if (src == parent.buttonDivide) {
        selectedAction = '/';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.displayField.setText("");
    } else if (src == parent.buttonMultiply) {
        selectedAction = '*';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.displayField.setText("");
    } else if (src == parent.buttonSquareRt) {
        selectedAction = 's';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.displayField.setText("");
    } else if (src == parent.buttonPercentage){
        selectedAction = 'p';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.displayField.setText("");
    } else if (src == parent.buttonPlusMinus){
        selectedAction = 'm';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.displayField.setText("");
    }

    else if (src == parent.buttonEqual) {
        // Perform the calculations based on selectedAction
        // update the value of the variable currentResult
        // and display the result
        if (selectedAction == '+') {
            currentResult += displayValue;
            // Convert the result to String by concatenating
            // to an empty string and display it
            parent.displayField.setText("" + currentResult);
        } else if (selectedAction == '-') {
            currentResult -= displayValue;
            parent.displayField.setText("" + currentResult);
        } else if (selectedAction == '/') {
            currentResult /= displayValue;
            parent.displayField.setText("" + currentResult);
        } else if (selectedAction == '*') {
            currentResult *= displayValue;
            parent.displayField.setText("" + currentResult);
        } else if (selectedAction == 's') {
            currentResult = Math.sqrt(displayValue);
            parent.displayField.setText("" + currentResult);
        } else if (selectedAction == 'p') {
            currentResult = currentResult / 100;
            parent.displayField.setText("" + currentResult);
        } else if (selectedAction == 'm') {
            displayValue = currentResult * -1;
            parent.displayField.setText("" + currentResult);
        }

    } else {
        // For all numeric buttons append the button's
        // label to the text field
        String clickedButtonLabel = clickedButton.getText();
        parent.displayField.setText(dispFieldText + clickedButtonLabel);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can get some idea from here: https://github.com/alimranahmed/CI-Calculator

Comment: Based on your code you would have to press the sqrt button and then the equals button for it to actually calculate and update the display field.  Based on your question above it sounds like you aren't pressing the equals button?

Comment: If you look closely, you will see that all calculation is triggered by the equal button. To change this behaviour, just move the desired operation out from the equal button code block and move into the corresponding block above it.

Comment: One word of advice: Learn to write less code.  Skip ahead to the array and loop lessons.  Stay away from UI code until you have a better understanding of Java.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this code would work as expected where you would type a number like 64, then you would press the square root button - which would clear the displayField - then you would press the equals button, and it would display the result.

If you want to make it more obvious that you should be pressing the equals button to get the result, you might want to echo the users entry surrounded by text that represents the function to be performed, for example:

```
else if (src == parent.buttonSquareRt) {
    selectedAction = 's';
    currentResult = displayValue;
    parent.displayField.setText("sqrt(" + currentResult + ")");
}
```